# get_option issues

Tags: customization, loop

Hello the first thing I'm sorry for my poor english level.

I was looking some tutorial to use the customizer on wordpress for a theme from scratch. But I have some issues with get_option, I have no return. I put my code right bellow.

```
<?php
//==================================================
//============= Chargement des scripts =============
//==================================================

define('schweitzer_ver', '0.2');


// Chargement front end
function schweitzer_scripts(){

    // Chargement des styles
    //wp_enqueue_style( 'styles-bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    //  '', schweitzer_ver, 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array(), schweitzer_ver, 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'menu', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/menu.css',
        array(), schweitzer_ver, 'all' );


    // Chargement des scripts
    wp_enqueue_script( 'schweitzer_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/schweitzer.js',
        array('jquery'), schweitzer_ver, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'menu_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/menu.js',
        array('jquery'), schweitzer_ver, true );
    }

    // Intégration et mise en forme du menu
    function clean_custom_menus() {
        $menu_name = 'primary';
        if (($locations = get_nav_menu_locations()) && isset($locations[$menu_name])) {
            $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($locations[$menu_name]);
            $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
            // $menu_list = '<nav>' ."\n";
            $menu_list .= "\t\t\t\t". '<ul>' ."\n";

        foreach ((array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item) {
            $title = $menu_item->title;
            $url = $menu_item->url;
            $menu_list .= "\t\t\t\t\t". '<li><a href="'. $url .'">'. $title .'</a></li>' ."\n";
            }

        $menu_list .= "\t\t\t\t". '</ul>' ."\n";
        $menu_list .= "\t\t\t". '</nav>' ."\n";
        }

        else {
        $menu_list = 'Pas de menu défini';
        }
    echo $menu_list;
}



add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'schweitzer_scripts', 'clean_custom_menus');


//==================================================
//================= Configuration ==================
//==================================================

function schweitzer_setup ()
{

    // Active gestion des menus (avec plusieurs positions)
    register_nav_menus(array('primary'=>'principal'));

    // support des vignettes
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');

    // Retire générateur de version (sécurité !)
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');

    // Retire guillemets français
    remove_filter ('the_content', 'wptexturize');

    // Support du titre géré par WP (meilleur SEO)
    add_theme_support('title-tag');

}

    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'schweitzer_setup' );

//==================================================
//================ Options du theme ================
//==================================================

function schweitzer_customizer()
{

    //===== Variables =====
    // Couleur du menu
    $menu_color = get_option('menu_color','#2a2a2a');

    // Transparence du menu
    $menu_opacity = get_option('menu_opacity','0.5');

    // Nombre d'éléments dans le menu
    // $menu_element = get_option( 'menu_element' );

    ?>
    <style>
        nav li:nth-of-type(1){background-color: <?php echo $menu_color; ?>; opacity: <?php echo $menu_opacity; ?>}
        nav li:nth-of-type(2){background-color: <?php echo $menu_color; ?>; opacity: <?php echo $menu_opacity; ?>}
        nav li:nth-of-type(3){background-color: <?php echo $menu_color; ?>; opacity: <?php echo $menu_opacity; ?>}
        nav li:nth-of-type(4){background-color: <?php echo $menu_color; ?>; opacity: <?php echo $menu_opacity; ?>}
        nav li:nth-of-type(5){background-color: <?php echo $menu_color; ?>; opacity: <?php echo $menu_opacity; ?>}
    </style>
    <?php

}
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'schweitzer_customizer' );




function schweitzer_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {

        $wp_customize->add_section( 'menu_options' , array(
        'title' =>  'Réglage du Menu',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'menu_color' , array(
        'default' => '#000',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'menu_opacity' , array(
        'default' => '0.5',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control(
        new WP_Customize_Color_Control($wp_customize,
            'menu_color_selection',
            array('label' => 'Choix de la couleur',
                'section' => 'menu_options',
                'settings' => 'menu_color',
        )
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control(
        'menu_opacity_selection',
        array(
            'label'    => __( 'Transparence', 'schweitzer' ),
            'section'  => 'menu_options',
            'settings' => 'menu_opacity',
            'type'     => 'radio',
            'choices'  => array(
                '0'  => '0% (opaque)',
                '0.1' => '10 %',
                '0.2'  => '20 %',
                '0.3' => '30 %',
                '0.4'  => '40 %',
                '0.5' => '50 %',
                '0.6'  => '60 %',
                '0.7' => '70 %',
                '0.8' => '80 %',
                '0.9'  => '90 %',
                '1' => '100 % (transparent)',),
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'schweitzer_customize_register' );

function schweitzer_register_settings() {
    register_setting( 'menu_settings', 'my_option_name', 'intval' );
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'schweitzer_register_settings' );
```

This is my functions.php. The back end seems to work well but there is no trace of my "`menu_color`" options. Wp_head is in the index.php.

If you can help I will be very thanksfull.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution on another forum but if someone has the same problem than me here's the solution :

> For theme options modified through the $wp_customize, use get_theme_mod() instead of get_option() to retrieve the value.